# How do I mark/make the C drive unbootable while within Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, format

How do I reformat the boot drive or mark the boot drive as unbootable while booted into Windows XP?

***Caveat***: I want to be able to do this without having to boot to another type of media to do this. There are other workarounds to this which will not be useful to me.

Why would I want to do this? Basically the situation is I'm trying to install linux on an old junker. The USB keyboard is not usable until after the "Press F2 to enter BIOS, F12 to..." prompt. The computer has no PS2 ports. So I can't enter the bios to change the boot sequence, which unfortunately is C before both CDROM and USB. (Yes, I already tried to reset the bios.) I'm trying to avoid taking the hard drive out and installing it into another computer, for a variety of different reasons. If the hard drive is blank, it will not attempt to boot from the C drive and will boot from my linux CD. I'm also trying to avoid using Wubi.

Comment: Can't do it, you could only really cause Windows to fail to boot but this would be after the BIOS boot stage. You may want to look into wiping your MBR.

Comment: Now that IS a good idea.

Comment: Success! I used HxD to wipe the first several sectors of the hard drive. After reboot, it booted straight to CDRom. If you add your comment as a question, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could only really cause Windows to fail to boot but this would be after the BIOS boot stage.

You may want to look at wiping your MBR.

**UPDATE:** 
Using HxD to wipe the first several sectors of the hard drive caused the PC to boot to CD